# Is there a possibility to make text field in SQLite to point to a different field?

Tags: database, sqlite, pointers

I have a DB which I access through SQLite. 
I have a text field with a url to the media file inside that field (named here UrlField).

Is there a possibility (after downloading the files and inserting them as blobs to different table - Blob table with BlobValue field) to make UrlField value point to BlobField value and to access blobs through UrlField?

Thanks,
JRoma

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about foreign keys and joins. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE blob_table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, image_data BLOB);
CREATE TABLE url_table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, url TEXT,
                       blob_id INTEGER REFERENCES blob_table(id));
INSERT INTO blob_table VALUES (1, 'I''m an image!');
INSERT INTO url_table(url, blob_id) VALUES ('http//x.com/bar.png', 1);

SELECT image_data
FROM url_table AS u
JOIN blob_table AS b ON u.blob_id = b.id
WHERE u.url = 'http://x.com/bar.png';
```

The idea is that table B stores the id of a row in table A, and then the two tables are joined together on that common value, making a new pseudo-table with both rows values in each of its rows.

Comment: Huh. Apparently SO doesn't like answers that contain the concatenated strings 'http://' and 'foo.com'.